# Agrupar y eliminar datos repetidos en listas c#

Tags: c#, .net

quisiera saber como lograr agrupar y eliminar datos repetidos, por ejemplo tengo esta clase:

```
public class Objeto
{
        public string atributo1{ get; set; }
        public string atributo2{ get; set; }
}
```

y quiero "depurar" los objetos repetidos, intente lo siguiente, pero no funciona.

```
List<Objeto> ListaObjetos = new List<Objeto>();

var obj1 = new Objeto{atributo1="atributo1", atributo2="atributo2"}
ListaObjetos.add(obj1);

var obj2 = new Objeto{atributo1="atributo1", atributo2="atributo2"}
ListaObjetos.add(obj2);



List<Objeto> listAgrupada = new List<Objeto>();

foreach(var obj in ListaObjetos)
{
  if(!listAgrupada.contains(obj))
     listAgrupada.add(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrias ayudarte con `linq`

```
vare result = (from item in ListaObjetos
               group item by new { item.atributo1, item.atributo1 } into g
               select new Objeto()
               { 
                  atributo1 = g.Key.atributo1,
                  atributo2 = g.Key.atributo2,
               }).Tolist();
```

como veras queda muy simple

[Agrupar los resultados de consultas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results)

Answer (score 0):

Para cuando verificas antes de agregarlos cambia tu condicion por:

```
if(!listAgrupada.Any(o=> o.Atributo1== obj.Atributo1 & o.Attribut2==obj.Atributo2))
     listAgrupada.add(obj);
```

Comment: El uso de `Distinct` **NO** va a funcionar sin hacer un override de `Equals`, ya que va a comparar las referencias, y ambos objetos, si bien tienen el mismo valor en sus propiedades no son el mismo.

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal gracias ya elimine esa opcion , con la comparacion sugerida se arregla el problema, gracais.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor, sería usar [`Enumerable.Union`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=netframework-4.7.2), que, con dos `IEnumerable<T>` nos devolverá la [unión de ambos conjuntos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uni%C3%B3n_de_conjuntos). Pero para esto, vamos a tener que sobreescribir [`Object.Equals`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.7.2) de modo que compare sólo valores y no referencias.

Para hacer esto más sencillo vamos a usar [`IEquatable<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2), para implementarlo, vamos a hacer lo siguiente:

```
/// <summary>
/// Heredo de la interface <see cref="IEquatable{T}"/>
/// </summary>
public class Objeto : IEquatable<Objeto>
{
    public string atributo1 { get; set; }
    public string atributo2 { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Implemento el método Equals de la interface <see cref="IEquatable{T}"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other">El segundo objeto con el que lo compararemos.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool Equals(Objeto other)
    {
        //Si el objeto es null la igualdad será falsa..
        if(other==null)return false;
        //Caso contario, chequeo que las propiedades atributo1 y atributo2 sean iguales en ambos objetos.
        return atributo1==other.atributo1&&atributo2==other.atributo2;
    }

    //Sobreescribo Equals ejecutando el que se implementó por IEquatable{T} de modo tipado.
    public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as Objeto);

    //Sobreescribo GetHashCode asegurándome que si Equals es verdadero, ambos objetos deben tener el mismo HashCode.
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        //XOR de ambos atributos
        return atributo1.GetHashCode() ^ atributo2.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

De esta manera, nosotros ahora, podríamos utilizar [`Enumerable.Union`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=netframework-4.7.2) con objetos de tipo `Objeto`, por lo que..

```
List<Objeto> list1 = new List<Objeto>{new Objeto{atributo1="Dato1", atributo2 = "Dato2"}};
List<Objeto> list2 = new List<Objeto>
{
    new Objeto{atributo1="Dato1", atributo2 = "Dato2"},
    new Objeto{atributo1="Dato3", atributo2 = "Dato4"}
};

//Obtengo la unión entre ambas listas
var listaDefinitiva = list1.Union(list2);

foreach (var objeto in listaDefinitiva)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Atributo1: {0}\t Atributo2: {1}",objeto.atributo1,objeto.atributo2);
}
```

El output de la consola sería

> ```
> Atributo1: Dato1         Atributo2: Dato2
> Atributo1: Dato3         Atributo2: Dato4
> ```

Otra opción es la de usar [`Enumerable.Concat`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=netframework-4.7.2) para juntar ambas listas, y luego con [`Enumerable.Distinct`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.7.2) descartar los duplicados.

```
var listaDefinitiva = list1.Concat(list2).Distinct();
```

El resultado sería el mismo que el de usar union.

*Aclaración: para usar [`Enumerable.Distinct`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.7.2) también es necesario sobreescribir [`Object.Equals`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.7.2)*